# Router marionette backbone remove/rename base url (index.html)

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette, router

Hello I've done a small router in backbone.marionette.

How can I remove/rename the "index.html" of my `index.html#test1`, `index.html#test2`?

Any ideas?

Comment: what is your server side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a job for your server configuration: you need it to rewrite the routes with `index.html` to remove it but still perform the appropriate actions (e.g. using Apache's modrewrite, I believe).